# Bounds on the product of $n$ real numbers given their sum.

Tags: real-analysis

What are the best known bounds for the product of $n$ positive real numbers (call them $x_i$) given their sum?  I'd like to break this into three cases:

$1)$ $0 \lt x_i \lt 1$

$2)$ $1 \leq x_i$

$3)$ $1 \lt x_i$

For all cases I can show that:

$$\prod_i x_i \lt e^{\sum_i x_i}$$
through logging and then taking the exponential.  Also, (perhaps trivially) for 1) we know: $$\prod_i x_i \lt \sum_i x_i$$. Can we do better in finding a bound knowing just the sum? How about a lower bound?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is the [**Arithmetic Mean Geometric Mean Inequality:**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means) $$\sqrt[n]{a_1a_2\cdots a_n}\le\frac{a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n}{n}.$$

This is sharp if the $a_i$ are all equal.

The lower bound is $0$.

Comment: Oops. I meant the $x_i$ are positive, not non-negative. This was implied by my three cases but not my initial wording. AM-GM totally slipped my mind.

Comment: In the positive case, there is no min, but we can get as close to $0$ as we please.

Answer (score 0):

No lower bound will be possible because just one number being zero implies a product is zero, whereas the same is not true for a sum. (Something interesting may be possible in the case they are bounded away from zero, but I would be very surprised). Apart from AM-GM, I don't think there's any other interesting relations really.

One thing to think about with trying to decide if these types of equalities are possible is if they are "dimensionally consistent" - like if you multiply every number by a constant, does it "pull out and cancel off" on each side? If not you it has to be false considering the cases where the constant is large or small. And, digressing slightly, when you look at integral bounds like Holder's inequality, replacing f(x) with f(cx) and seeing if it all works out.